# String equality in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to check the equality of two strings however it seems that my code it doesnt work properly:

```
listes = []
for row in my_lines:
    split = re.split(r' +', row)
    print split[0], ":size of the split: ", len(split)
    if str(split[0]) == '5':
        print "...."
```

The printed message from my print before the if statement is the following:

```
'5' :size of the split:  3
'4' :size of the split:  4
'6' :size of the split:  3
'6' :size of the split:  4
'F' :size of the split:  4
'6' :size of the split:  4
'F' :size of the split:  4
'6' :size of the split:  4
```

However the if statement does not work. What could have been wrong here?

Comment: It appears that your `split[x]` contains a string of the form `"'x'"`, but you're only comparing it to `"x"`.

Comment: Looks like the string is actually `'5' `  with single quotation marks and space.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your `split[0]` content itself has `'` as the part of the string based on the output you mentioned. You need to either compare it like:

```
  if str(split[0]) == "'5'":  
  #                    ^ ^ single quotes here
```

OR, remove `'` from start and end of row as:

```
 if str(split[0])[1:-1] == "5":
 #                ^  ^ remove first and last character from string
```